# Extracting and Splitting numbers and characters from string in R

Tags: r, string, strsplit

I am trying to split extract and split numbers and characters from strings. I also want to remove a few characters and numbers at the end of each string.
For example, I have following strings.

```
dm<-c("2December2005MOMENT55", "3December2005ROYALS56", "1July2012ANGELS57")
```

I want to make them as

```
Day Month    Year
2   December 2005
3   December 2005
1   July     2012
```

Split and extract the values and put them under different variables.

I was trying this with `strsplit` command. But I couldn't proceed enough. I am really sorry I don't have codes for this.

I hope can have any command or code suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: If you're after dates, why not use something like `strptime(dm, "%d%B%Y", tz = "GMT")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Convert to a date object (format `'%d%B%Y'` ( given the provided example))
2. Use `year`, `mday` and `month` to get the data.frame you want

---

```
df <- data.frame(string = dm, date = as.Date(dm,format = '%d%B%Y'))
df[c('Day','Month','Year')] <- with(df, list(mday(date), 
                                             month.name[month(date)],
                                             year(date)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `regex` solution:

```
library(stringr)
str_match(dm, "(^[0-9]{1,3})([A-z]+)([0-9]{4})")[, 2:4]
##      [,1] [,2]       [,3]  
## [1,] "2"  "December" "2005"
## [2,] "3"  "December" "2005"
## [3,] "1"  "July"     "2012"
```